# Positioning Different in Safari and Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, safari, css-position

Hi all,

I'm making a website for a client and I've received a base template image, no HTML, CSS :(.

I'm trying to reproduce the template with my own HTML and CSS, but I'm encountering a problem.

I'm trying to absolute-position a button over the text "LOGIN" in the image. I've set the opacity to .4 so that you can see both the button (faint rectangle) and the text it's trying to cover (LOGIN >).

The first image below is the whole thing in Safari.

[image: Safari]

This picture, however, is the same thing with the same CSS in Firefox. Notice how the button is way above, where in the first case it was below.

[image: Firefox]

How do I fix this? It's a big problem, and although I could leave it how it is, I'd really like to fix it.

Thanks in advance!

****EDIT****:

People are asking for code so here it is. **I'm having the same problem with input text boxes so I'm posting the code for that.**

CSS first:

```
input.fp-login-u {
    position: relative;
    top: 74px;
    left: 740px;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Then the HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="fp-login-u" />
```

Everything is in `<header>` tags, margins and padding are defined and not the problem (on those elements).

****EDIT AGAIN****:

Sorry for being unclear.

The white text "LOGIN" is the background image of the div that holds all this content. Once I position the faded login button properly over it, I will remove it.

The new faded button, not the white text, is what is moving.

Comment: Could you please explain where the 'login' text comes from? Is it the value of the input? Are you trying to create a button with a custom background and HTML text?

Comment: Relative to the rest of the page, which of the two elements appears at a different position in FF vs Safari, the button or the white "LOGIN"? Is the white "LOGIN" an image or is it (at least partly) plain text? Might be helpful to see the code for that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you show some code I can look at what's going wrong. Otherwise I would say a workaround is to use relative positioning and set margins

```
#login {
    margin: 10px 30px 0px 30px;
}
```

Another option is to use it's own background image (same image you were already using), and obviously change the position values to your needs. This won't take extra load time because they have already loaded the image.

```
#login {
    margin: 10px 30px 0px 30px;
    background-image: url(images/top_banner.jpg);
    background-position: -30px -233px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use relative positioning. This will make your life much easier as you can position it relative to the screen size with top, left, right, bottom. Make sure you check it in IE though as that gets thrown off a little bit, but unfortunately is not something you can fix.

Answer (score 0):

Without posting code, I can only suggest that you make sure you're:

1. Using a CSS Reset
2. The container item of your 'absolute-position' button is set to "position: relative;"
3. The container item of your 'absolute-position' button has its padding and margin reset

Comment: I am using the CSS Reset by Eric Meyer, I am using "position: relative" (sorry, typo), and I have reset margins and padding. :) I've read that I'm trying to be "pixel-perfect", and it's true. Is it really that hard?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has it's own idea of how buttons and inputs are rendered. There seems to be an issue with padding in input elements and the Gecko engine. *Sometimes* this snippet helps me out:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner, input::-moz-focus-inner { border: 0; padding: 0; }
```

I can't say for sure if it will fix your problem, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Style the input so that the Login Button image is a background-image, and then as far as your text is concerned, you can do text-indent: -9999px;